# Creating multiple children for a node in jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

```
self.handleChildNodes = function(pageFileArray) {
    var node = $("#move-folder-list").jstree("get_selected");
    alert(node.attr("id"));
    $.each(pageFileArray, function(index, item) { 
        $("#move-folder-list").jstree("create", node, "inside",
          {attr : {id: index}, data: item.name}, false, true);
    });
}
```

In the above code snapshot I'm able to create only one child node when I use the inside option but when i use after I am able to create all the child nodes, but not able to get the tree structure. The error I'm getting says `li has no addBack method`, and I don't know what that means.

Comment: Which line is the error generated at? You don't call any methods named `addBack` in this code snippet, so it sounds as if the error is within the plugin code itself (which could mean you are using the API wrong, or there is a bug). Check your JS console to see the details on where the error occurs.

Comment: Hi nbrooks, this is the error i'm getting deep inside the jquery.jstree.js file. However, i'm not even sure what this error is pointing at as the same above code is working when i set the option : "after" !!! I've tried almost every place i can look at still no use. My jstree creation is aslo very bare structure with nothing but a few plugins and a bind event specified.

Comment: And also in the jquery plugin here's where the error is generated. my jquery version is 1.9.1.(function ($) {
 $.jstree.plugin("html_data", {
  __init : function () { 
   // this used to use html() and clean the whitespace, but this way any attached data was lost
   this.data.html_data.original_container_html = this.get_container().find(" > ul > li").clone(true);
   // remove white space from LI node - otherwise nodes appear a bit to the right
   this.data.html_data.original_container_html.find("li").addBack().contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }).remove();